# "No space left on device" on device with lots of space

Tags: hard-drive, services

Today, every time I've run `sudo service XXX restart` I'm getting the error `Error: No space left on device`. I have 700+ GB of disk free, and I have everything on a single root partition, so I can't figure out what's going on.

`df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           582M  8.8M  574M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       912G  188G  678G  22% /
tmpfs           2.9G  160K  2.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           582M   48K  582M   1% /run/user/1000
encfs           912G  188G  678G  22% /home/jeremy/Private
```

`df -i`

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             740426    544   739882    1% /dev
tmpfs            744747    795   743952    1% /run
/dev/sda1      60669952 521864 60148088    1% /
tmpfs            744747      8   744739    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            744747      7   744740    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            744747     17   744730    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs            744747     13   744734    1% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs            744747     29   744718    1% /run/user/1000
encfs          60669952 521864 60148088    1% /home/jeremy/Private
```

Comment: Which service were you trying to restart? Does the system complain about disk space when you download/create files or when installing new software?

Comment: please show the disk layout from `df -h`.

Comment: Which service? Are you sure the message relates to your main disk?

Comment: @EduardoCola both `network-manager` and `ssh`. No complaints when doing normal IO things

@Rinzwind `df -h` looks good. Nothing is over 22% used

Comment: Please add the output of `df -i` into your post.

Comment: Another chance is that the restart of the service tries to use lots of temporary files. `/run/user/1000` is limited by `systemd`, in your case to `582M`. Check whether during the restart of the service, that fills up, e.g. with `watch -n0.2 df -h`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file system has enough free inodes available, using the following:

```
df -i /
```

If your partition has 100% IUse then you have run out of inodes and the only easy way forward is to try and remove some unnecessary files to free up the inodes. I am pretty sure it is impossible to add inodes on most file systems after it has been created, so deleting files may be the only way forward.